# Selectbox selected Item color:

Tags: css

Can anybody help me. I would like to change the selected item color of select box from system generated dark blue color. Is it possible with css.I have tried different style properties such as background etc. But the color didn't changed.

Comment: you ask 11 question , and not accept one of them, why?

Answer (score 0):

It looks that you can customize the initial font, color, background, etc... but the pseudo classes `hover` or `active` don't appear to do anything...

You may be out of luck :(

The only other option that comes to mind is a roll-your-own drop down, wherein you could customize everything.

Answer (score 0):

it looks that you can customize the initial font, color, background, etc... but the pseudo classes hover or active don't appear to do anything...

You may be out of luck :(

The only other option that comes to mind is a roll-your-own drop down, wherein you could customize everything